# SQL to calculate number of values for each day based on a max value from previous date

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table in PostgreSQL database which stores data about words from a book and pages where those words occur. Something like this:

```
 headword | dict_pages       |   timestamp_updated    
----------+------------------+------------------------
 abcdefg  | {229}            | 2023-07-28 14:49:13+00
 ccdsd    | {213}            | 2023-07-28 18:48:11+00
 zdx      | {228}            | 2023-07-27 18:37:42+00
 xcdferc  | {227, 228}       | 2023-07-27 14:47:55+00
```

I would like to know, how many pages were processed for any particular day. Here is how I am doing this now:

```
SELECT
    to_char(timestamp_updated, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as dt,
    count(distinct(page_num))
FROM dictionary_word dtw, unnest(dict_pages) page_num
WHERE dict_pages IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY dt ASC
```

My goals is to get how many **new pages** were processed. Old pages that were processed some time ago are not relevant for this statistics.

From example above, with my existing query I will get the following:

```
2023-07-27 - 2
2023-07-28 - 2
```

But word `ccdsd` were added few days/weeks/months ago already, so page `213` should be excluded from calculation of number of processed pages. I think that solution for this might be getting maximum page number from the previous day, `2023-07-27` which is `228`, then for the current day calculate only numbers (pages) which are greater than `228`.

Is there any elegant way to achieve this with SQL?

Comment: Hi. What is the logic behind `timestamp_updated` column then?

Comment: On each addition/update of the `dict_pages` column `timestamp_updated` will be updated to current timestamp

Comment: In case of `'ccdsd' | {213} | '2023-07-28'` this logic is misleading. If we follow the logic that the pages can't be deleted, only can be added.

Comment: On each addition/update of the `dict_pages` column `timestamp_updated` will be updated to current timestamp. This table hold words from the dictionary, which are sorted in alphabetical order, so in most cases word will not repeat once we met it. But sometime it appears again (in examples), etc. In general this is not a big problem since this statistics is not used for salary calculation or something like that. Basic logic is to see the progress of how many new words from dictionary were added to database and on which page this word exists.

Comment: You have a logic hole.  If there is ever a page that contains only `headword` values that all appear in other pages, then that page cannot be counted correctly because it will not have a `timestamp_updated` column to associate that page with the correct date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be rephrased as follows:
*Calculate the number of daily processed unique pages while filtering pages which are less than the last day maximum page.*

[**DB fiddle with step-by-step queries**](https://dbfiddle.uk/caxX4kCE)

1. If you use **PostgreSQL 11+**:

```
select day_date, count(distinct(page)) as page_count
from 
(select 
    to_char(timestamp_updated, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as day_date, 
    page,
    first_value(page) over (
        order by to_char(timestamp_updated, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        groups between 1 preceding and current row
    ) as prev_day_max_page 
from dictionary_word, unnest(dict_pages) page
) prev_day_page_data
where page >= prev_day_max_page
group by day_date
order by day_date;
```

`GROUPS` window helps aggregate all rows from the previous and current date group.
Documentation **[link_1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)** and **[link_2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)**.

2. **Less elegant approach:**

```
with all_pages as (
    select
        to_char(timestamp_updated, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as day_date,
        page
    from dictionary_word dtw, unnest(dict_pages) page
)
select day_date, count(distinct(page)) as pages_count
from all_pages
join (
    select
        day_date,
        coalesce(
              lag(daily_max_page) over (order by day_date), 
              daily_max_page
        ) as prev_max_page
    from (
          select
              to_char(timestamp_updated, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as day_date,
              max(page::integer) as daily_max_page
          from dictionary_word dtw, unnest(dict_pages) page
          group by day_date
          -- order by day_date
    ) s
) prev_day_max_page_stat using (day_date)
where page::integer >= prev_max_page
group by day_date
order by day_date;
```

**Details:**

1. `all_pages` results in all page numbers from `unnest(dict_pages)` operation.
2. `prev_day_max_page_stat` query calculates the max page number before the current day.
3. The final query counts unique `pages_count` processed day by day.
   It groups pages by the `day_date` field and filters the values using the filter
   `where page::integer >= prev_max_page`.

**Improved example:**
I have improved insert statements to check the query for correctness. In the screenshot below you can see that pages with a value which is less than the previous day's max value are not included in the result.
**[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQQkG.png)**

| day_date | pages_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-07-26 | 1 |
| 2023-07-27 | 2 |
| 2023-07-28 | 1 |

Comment: Almost... But it calculates words, not pages.https://dbfiddle.uk/ilpAH8LW
I changed subquery to ```-- unnested data with corresponding max_page_num
select 
      to_char(timestamp_updated, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as time_upd,
      -- select max_page_num from 'dict_pages' unnested array value
      max(page_num::integer) over(partition by to_char(timestamp_updated, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as max_page_num
from dictionary_word dtw, unnest(dict_pages) page_num
order by time_upd;``` to get max page, but still unable to figure out how to count number of distinct pages if page is equals or greater than previous

Comment: @5w0rdf1sh thanks for checking my answer. I've rewritten the whole query, check please.

Answer (score 0):

The query below first `unnest`s the page number arrays, and then during the aggregation, filters out any headword with a corresponding `dict_page` that has been processed at an earlier date (i.e there exists a `dict_page` greater than or equal to the `dict_page` in question with a smaller timestamp):

```
with dt as (
   select date(d.timestamp_updated) date, d.headword, c::int 
   from dictionary_word d cross join unnest(d.dict_pages) c
)
select d.date, count(distinct d.headword) c from dt d 
where not exists (select 1 from dt d1 where d.c <= d1.c and d1.date < d.date)
group by d.date
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/21iIkhwI)